# Improve performance in linq query

Tags: vb.net, linq

We have a linq query as shown below to display items first it should display records matching with the text and next with if the text contains in the string.But it is causing lot of performance issue. Could any one pls help how to improve it.

```
Dim result1 = From entry As IAutoCompleteEntry In oldList
             Where entry.ToString.ToUpper.Contains(Me.Text.ToUpper())
             Order By entry.ToString.IndexOf(Me.Text.ToUpper()), entry.ToString.ToUpper.StartsWith(Me.Text.ToUpper())
              Descending
             Select entry
```

Comment: What does your `ToString()` method for the `entry` objects look like?

Comment: Public Interface IAutoCompleteEntry
        ReadOnly Property MatchStrings() As String()

    End Interface

Comment: Don't do `.ToUpper()` in your query.  Also, your query doesn't seem to do what you describe.  You are sorting based on where in the string it is contained, not just if it matches first, then if it is contained.  If that is what you really wanted, then use `.Contains` not `.IndexOf`. You say "first it should display records matching with the text", but you don't test or order if they match, you order by if it startswith (which seems redundant with IndexOf as well)

Comment: Hi Robert,
 Thanks for your reply my requirement is as explained below. I have textbox where the user will enter the name of a person like sha so all the persons name which starts with sha needs to be displayed in the list first then we need to display names having sha in any position of the names for ex:
sharath
shankar
shamprasad
prashanth
etc...

Answer (score 1):

You are calling ToUpper() at several places. Is it possible to get your list/array to have a ToUpper() before you get into this linq query?
I think you can also have another column for entry.ToString.IndexOf(Me.Text.ToUpper()), entry.ToString.ToUpper.StartsWith(Me.Text.ToUpper()) before getting to this linq query.
It might improve on performance....

Answer (score 1):

First, I'm not sure what the significance of the .StartWith has. Since you are already getting the IndexOf, you would already know the answer of StartsWith (it should be 0).

Next, you really shouldn't be using ToUpper (as @RobertMcKee mentioned), instead you should be using case insensitive comparisons. In that case, you shouldn't need the .ToUpper's anymore either...

Finally, I was actually going to say use contains for your second statement, but you probably don't even need it. You could just sort descending based on your entry variable. Here is an updated query I wrote up:

```
dim result1 = From entry As IAutoCompleteEntry In oldList
              Where (entry.IndexOf(Me.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) <> -1)
              Order By entry Descending
              Select entry
```

Comment: Hi Dylan,
Thanks for the above query if we use the above query it is only displaying values equal to the text we entered but we need to display two kinds of names i.e first we display names starting with the characters entered in the textbox for ex : If user enters sha we need to fill the list as shown below :
for ex:
sharath
shankar
shamprasad
prashanth
 similar to google search we will get autocomplete suggestions.